# Execute a prepared query c# mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, variables

can anyone explain me how to use executePreparedQuery?
I want to fill variables into my MySql database.

Getting some error's using:

```
API.exported.database.executePreparedQuery("INSERT INTO users (ID,username,password) VALUES('','testing3',pass)","pass","password123456");
```

:

```
public void executePreparedQuery(string sql, Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            conn.Open();
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in parameters)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(entry.Key, entry.Value);
            }
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            API.consoleOutput("DATABASE: [ERROR] " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you :)

Comment: it does not seemn that you are passing a dictionary<string, string> as parameter to the method

Comment: Okay, can you give me an example of API.exported.database.executePreparedQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a correct Dictionary to the `executePreparedQuery` method:

```
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
dic.Add("pass", "password123456");

API.exported.database.executePreparedQuery("INSERT INTO users (ID,username,password) VALUES('','testing3',pass)",dic);
```

Comment: Thanks but got:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unknown column 'pass' in 'field list'

Comment: Changed the "pass" into "?pass", it's working. thank you :)